# Possible to load balance across nodejs servers using apache

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, https, load-balancing

Is it possible to load balance across a set of nodejs servers using apache?  I would also need to configure apache with a cert to provide ssl and only serve out https requests.

Simple setup would be 2 apache servers that would be my load balancers.  All requests would come into one of those 2 load balancers over https.

From there the load balancers would need to determine which server to route the request to.  This would be one of 6 servers that are all running the same node process.

I know there is mod_cluster, but I have only used that with JBoss setup and not really sure if this would work with nodejs servers.

I also realize this might not be the best setup as node is single threaded and I could try something like node cluster.  However node cluster seems to scale vertically instead of horizontally.

I also know there is nginx and haproxy, although I have never used either of them and have a lot more experience with apache.  Also not sure if haproxy and nginx support allowing only ssl connections with a certificate.

Is this type of load balancing possible w/ apache and if so how?

Answer (score 5):

The use of apache is independt of the server used behind if you use the mod_proxy module. So you can also look at all the apache->tomcat examples using mod_proxy.

After questions how to do it I added the following example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyRequests off

        ServerName domain.com

        <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                # WebHead1
                BalancerMember http://10.176.42.144:80
                # WebHead2
                BalancerMember http://10.176.42.148:80

                # Security "technically we aren't blocking
                # anyone but this the place to make those
                # chages
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from none
                Allow from all

                # Load Balancer Settings
                # We will be configuring a simple Round
                # Robin style load balancer.  This means
                # that all webheads take an equal share of
                # of the load.
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests

        </Proxy>

        # balancer-manager
        # This tool is built into the mod_proxy_balancer
        # module and will allow you to do some simple
        # modifications to the balanced group via a gui
        # web interface.
        <Location /balancer-manager>
                SetHandler balancer-manager

                # I recommend locking this one down to your
                # your office
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        # Point of Balance
        # This setting will allow to explicitly name the
        # the location in the site that we want to be
        # balanced, in this example we will balance "/"
        # or everything in the site.
        ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
        ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: mod_proxy can load balance?  Is that the same as mod_proxy_balancer that @madness refereed?

Comment: Yes mod_proxy can. I added an example.

Comment: this is so useful and powerful.. bless you

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, if you are asking how to setup Apache Load Balancers, [Check this out](http://blog.search-computing.net/2010/04/load-balancing-with-apache-a-tutorial-on-mod_proxy_balancer-installation-and-configuration/).

Have you seen `node-http-proxy`? [Great little walkthrough here](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/136/Horizontally-Scaling-Node.js-and-WebSockets-with-Redis) not too intimidating if you want to keep it all Node.

Comment: ah, didn't know about mod_proxy_balancer.  I will give that a go.  I stumbled upon node-http-proxy, but I also need to setup ssl (hence apache).  can node-http-proxy do ssl, or do I just throw apache in front of node-http-proxy?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: That walk through covers using certs.